# How does one write a book on a new framework?

Tags: books, technical-writing

How are authors able to write a book on a framework that is just released? A framework like spring is updated, and a book is released in the next day. Is this typically by people who are direct contributors? Are they basing it off of beta/alpha versions?

I find this rather difficult to understand as that documentation is rarely up to snuff by the time the framework is updated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those who write books about frameworks are generally involved in the framework they are writing about, they have access to documentation and pre-release versions of the framework. They aren't random people that know about programming, they likely contacted the development team about writing a book and got the information or were asked by the development team to write a book. Also good frameworks keep their documentation up to date, its part of being a good framework, though the general public may not have access to the most up to date documentation.

Comment: There are secret documentations?!!! I knew it was a conspiracy!

Comment: @monksy its not really secret, its just lag between newest version and released version, which happens even with internet distribution, especially with 3rd party distributors.

Comment: Thats no fun to put it that way. Conspiracies are amusing.